# nbconvert using command line, WARNING | pattern ' ' matched no files

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

The memory for a jupyter notebook has exceeded the notebooks limit. As soon as I open the notebook it crashes. I am looking to use nbconvert to clear the output of the notebook so that it will not crash and I can change the code. Here is the line I am using:

```
jupyter nbconvert --clear-output --inplace notebook_name.ipynb
```

The error message I receive is

```
WARNING | pattern 'notebook_name.ipynb' matched no files
```

I have checked that the spelling of the notebook is correct and that the command line is operating on the same path as the file `C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Documents>`

Comment: I just tried your exact command on a jupyter notebook I have, and it went through. If you're absolutely positive you're running your command from `C:\Users\myname\OneDrive\Documents`, and that `notebook_name.ipynb` is spelled correctly, could it perhaps have something to do with the OneDrive folder? Is that a network-mapped folder or something?

Comment: So I was using the wrong directory, I wasn't listing the sub folder that the file was in and since I started a terminal using jupyter in that sub folder and it gave me that directory I thought I thought I wouldn't need it. Now I know I always do. Zoltan!

Comment: If anyone using **colab** is having this issue, you need to mount your drive and then provide the absolute path of the notebook file.